# Can we change up the favicon image for chats?

Tags: feature-request, chat, favicon

So, I don't know how user-specific this is, but I have (had, at the moment Main is unpinned so I stop getting them mixed up) both the chat and the Main site pinned on my browser.

Being as pinned tabs only show the sites favicon image, I was wondering if we could have a slight but noticeable variation of the chat icon so that I could easily tell the difference?

If it's not a pinned tab (for me), it's liable to be closed by accident at any given point. This would save me minor temper tantrums (exaggeration, but it's still slightly annoying).

Suggestion: KISS. You could literally flip the image around and I would be happy!

Comment: [I went ahead and made you a userscript to solve this exceptional problem](https://gist.github.com/rlemon/c8fdc3b7385c59109b8a) - [here it is in action](http://i.imgur.com/dS9MkIn.png)

Comment: @rlemon, this just made my entire day. Hilarious.

Comment: Would love to see custom favicons per chat room - so I can differentiate between android an iOS rooms without having to go into them first.